# Allow shortcode for custom widget

Tags: widgets, shortcode

The following code allows shortcode parsing for 'text' widget:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

How to make a similar one for a custom widget?

I tried the following one but it didn't work:

```
add_filter('widget_CUSTOM_WIDGET_NAME', 'do_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
/**
 * Only allow shortcodes for a widget with a given title.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160246/26350
 */

function wpse_widget_shortcode( $text, $instance )
{
        // Only allow shortcodes for the widget with the following title:
        $title = 'Some Title'; 

        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

        if( isset( $instance['title'] ) 
            && mb_strtolower( $title ) === $instance['title'] 
        )
            $text = do_shortcode( $text );

        return $text;
}

add_filter( 'widget_text', 'wpse_widget_shortcode', 99, 2 );
```

where we target the given widget by it's title.

Comment: Thanks for the 'do_shortcode( $text );'! That was the key!